# What's the purpose of embedding #define's into a struct definition?

Tags: c, linux, struct

In a struct definition at: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/serial.h#L116
I found this:

```
struct serial_rs485 {
    __u32   flags;          /* RS485 feature flags */
#define SER_RS485_ENABLED       (1 << 0)    /* If enabled */
#define SER_RS485_RTS_ON_SEND       (1 << 1) /* Logical level for RTS pin when sending */
#define SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND    (1 << 2) /* Logical level for RTS pin after sent*/
#define SER_RS485_RX_DURING_TX      (1 << 4)
#define SER_RS485_TERMINATE_BUS     (1 << 5) /* Enable bus termination (if supported) */
    __u32   delay_rts_before_send;  /* Delay before send (milliseconds) */
    __u32   delay_rts_after_send;   /* Delay after send (milliseconds) */
    __u32   padding[5];     /* Memory is cheap, new structs
                       are a royal PITA .. */
};
```

What's the purpose of embedding `#define`'s into the struct definition?

Comment: Just to indicate what the flags in that struct are. It's for the reader, not the compiler.

Comment: It's simply the locality of reference principle being applied for the sake of the human reader of this definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not "embedded", they just happen to be located there. This does nothing to the `struct` itself. Remember that the preprocessor runs *before* the compiler sees the code; those will have been removed before the code compiles.

It makes sense for the code reader, since it keeps the `#define`s that deal with those fields close by.

I think they are not optimal, since the names of the symbols don't refer back to the member in the `struct` that they relate to.

So you'll have code doing:

```
struct serial_rs485 ser;

ser.flags = SER_RS485_ENABLED | SER_RS485_TERMINATE_BUS;
```

see how the right-hand side of the second line doesn't contain `FLAG`? If there are other `define`s for the same struct, it's easy to mix them up.

Often you add the name of the field, making it:

```
ser.flags = SER_RS485_FLAGS_ENABLED | SER_RS485_FLAGS_TERMINATE_BUS;
```

Comment: Why not use just comments to achieve the same?

Comment: @CinCout, how can you use comments, which are replaced by a space prior to preprocessing, to achieve text substitution to whatever the preprocessor allows?

Comment: @CinCout - Changes to the macro list will not automatically update the comments. The macros have to be somewhere. Might as well be close to their intended purpose.